Weird array length behaviour in C (memory corruption?)
I'm fully aware that, when passed to a function, an array just decays to a pointer, so you can't use sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]) to work out their size. However, I found out that one can use (&x)[1]-x, i.e. pointer arithmetic, so, out of curiosity, I tried to make a function that takes two arrays, works out their lengths, and joins them (using malloc to dynamically allocate a chunk of memory whose size is the sum of their lengths, times the size of an int).
This works:
#define ARR_LEN(a) ((&(a))[1]-(a))

void join (int a[], int b[]) {
  printf("%zu %zu", ARR_LEN(a), ARR_LEN(b));
}

int main() {
    int a[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int b[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    
    join(a, b);

    return 0;
}

It prints 3 5. However, changing the body of join to store ARR_LEN(a) in a local variable n, even after we print ARR_LEN(a) the first time:
int n;
    
printf("%zu %zu", ARR_LEN(a), ARR_LEN(b));
n = ARR_LEN(a);

causes seemingly pseudorandom results such as 18446708891292021383 5. Weirdest of all, it works fine, printing 3 5, when n is global, rather than local. Additionally, then printing the contents of n gives a different number to the first.
My guess is that, when a and b are on the stack, putting n on there somehow causes the C compiler to get confused about their sizes, although this issue persists when I declare n as int __attribute__ ((aligned (256))) to try to force it away from the other two (and any weird caching problems). When I print &a, &b and &n, I get something like:
0x7ffd680a8df8 0x7ffd680a8df0 0x7ffd680a8e00

While, when n is global, &n is 0x404200, since .data is below the stack. Additionally, when n is global and I instead, say, put a local variable m = ARR_LEN(b), a gets "corrupted" while ARR_LEN(b) is again correctly printed.

Your example lacks #include headers and a newline in printf(). Also, I get random numbers when building using gcc -O2 main.c -o main and 3 5 when building without -O2. The conclusion is that there is a UB somewhere here.

When passing arrays to functions, an argument like int a[] is exactly the same as int *a. You're passing pointers, and that breaks everything. Unless you have a sentinel (like the string null-terminator) the only way to get the length is to pass it as a separate argument.

Also note that your macro leads to undefined behavior. You can do arithmetic only on related pointers. That is, pointers that are both pointing to elements of the same array. The two pointers in your macro does not do that.

@Someprogrammerdude it is much worse  here (&(a))[1]  :) Not only arithmetics but actual dereferencing

Alright. In the future, I'll stop doing hacky array shenanigans, and go back to the nice world of pointers...

Changed it to int b[6] and I get the result 3 9. This is empirical proof that one cannot determine the length of an array in this way.


This works:

No, it does not. You were lucky. As function parameters int a[] and int *a mean exactly the same.

&(a) is giving the address of the local variable a (and it is a pointer to pointer in this case)
(&(a))[1] - derefences the pointer to pointer (&(a)) at index 1 which is undefined behaviour.

There is no way to take the size of the passed array, and no "hacky tricks" exist.
